# Cannot call function from viewChild element in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, viewchild

I am trying to trigger a click event programmatically using `@ViewChild` to call a function called open() I always get the error

`Cannot read property 'close' of undefined`

// Component

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {

    // Material Design Float Button 
    // https://github.com/GustavoCostaW/ngc-float-button
    ngcFloatButtonData: Object = {
        direction: 'up',
        open:false,
        onToggle: function(): void {
            this.open = !this.open;
        },
        close: function(): void {
            this.open = false;
        }
    };

    public elementRef;
    @ViewChild('float-button') public floatButton: ElementRef;

    constructor(
      public dialog: MatDialog,
      public el: ElementRef,
    ) {

    }

   decrement(): void {
      // try to call the function close()
      this.floatButton.close();
   }

} // end
```

// the component html

```
 <ngc-float-button
        id="float-button"
        icon="add"
        color="#c0392b"
        class="ngc-float-button-container ngc-float-button-main-button"
        (click)="ngcFloatButtonData.onToggle()"
        [direction]="ngcFloatButtonData.direction">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this.floatButton.close() please use nativeElement like

```
this.floatButton.nativeElement.close();
```

HTML:

```
<ngc-float-button
        id="float-button"
        #float-button
        icon="add"
        color="#c0392b"
        class="ngc-float-button-container ngc-float-button-main-button"
        (click)="ngcFloatButtonData.onToggle()"
        [direction]="ngcFloatButtonData.direction">
```

But I could not see where you are calling decrement method.

Comment: Thanks however I tried that and I get the error below?
`Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`

Comment: In HTML add the #float-button

Comment: the decrement() method is just part of the html component as follows :
`<i class="material-icons" (click)="decrement()">chevron_left</i>`

Comment: Did you try with adding the #float-button in your html in ngc-float-button tag?

Comment: thanks yeah I did #floatButton was it didn't accept #float-button - no joy yet I will keep trying thanks

Comment: Great! Then you need to change the viewChild as well. @ViewChild('floatButton') floatButton: ElementRef;  I up-ported your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the ViewChild annotation to just take the component ComponentWhatever instead of ElementRef, it will make it easier to understand what component are you calling.

And on HTML use the alias like #float-button aside of id property.

If it still tell you that close() method doesn't exist is probably cause it isn't initialized yet, check for initialition before calling the method.

Comment: hi @Rancio can you provide an example for this thanks?

Comment: To check if it's initialized, child something like should work:
    `initialize = false;
     
    //something
    
    ngOnInit() {
       this.initialize = true;
    }`

Parent:

   `@ViewChild('float-button') public floatButton: NgcFloatButton;
    // somecode
   decrement(): void {
      // try to call the function close()
      if(this.floatButton.initialize){
          this.floatButton.close();
      }
   }`